# How to detect postback in Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I'm using a single razor page (cshtml) that has a `form` and `@functions{}` section to capture an `OnPost()`. All of that works fine.

In the HTML section, I need to know when a post back has occurred and display a message. I'm not sure where or how that is done in a Razor Page. I've tried `IsPost` but that isn't available.

I created a string property in the class and set a value on it in `OnPost` but once I'm in the view, the property is `null`.

I assigned a value into `ViewData["mystring"]` but it is also null once I get into the view.

-- EDIT --
It seems the issue is that I'm trying to set a property in OnPost, which is the request. After OnPost, OnGet will always fire. OnGet is the Response. I can see the flip from `POST` to `GET` in `this.Request.Method`. So I lose any indication that a postback happened.

Any suggestions on how that is done?

Comment: There isn't really a thing that is postback. That was an abuse of http by web forms. What exactly do you need to know?

Comment: You capture the `POST` data in the `Controller` `ActionMethod` marked with the `POST` attribute.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: You saying I need to create a property, set it in the same method so it is available in the view where I want to display the message?

Comment: @4thSpace I think you might need to describe your problem in more detail.  What *exactly* are you trying to detect, and where?

Comment: What from the OP are you not sure about? All the details are there.

Comment: @4thSpace Are you *not* the OP?  Razor isn't called as part of the "postback".  It is handled in an `ActionMethod` on the `Controller` invoked by the matching `Route`.  You are using a lot of terms that don't really fit together, so I'm really unsure about your whole question.  It seems like you have a lot of technologies mixed up, and I would like you to describe exactly what you want, and *why* you want it, to make sure we are not dealing with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @4thSpace My apologies, it looks like I'm the one that got confused about tech.  I missed that this was using Razor Pages, and wasn't MVC.  With that in mind, your question does make perfect sense now.

Comment: "Postback" is handled in either `OnPost` or `OnPostAsync` of the **model**.  Properties on the model are included in the model binding if the property has the `BindProperty` attribute applied to it (you didn't mention if you have this attribute or not on the property).  Are you calling `ModelState.IsValid`?

Comment: Yes - I'm the Original Poster. `BindProperty` doesn't help. Even when the property is set in `OnPostAsync`, `Model.MyProperty` is still null. But the same property works fine if set on `OnGet()`. Maybe there is some difference with setting during the Request (`OnPost()`) vs Response (`OnGet()`)?

Comment: Regardless of these details, the goal is to simply display a message in the view that "Your post was submitted".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use use [Post-Redirect-Get](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/06/05/post-redirect-get-and-tempdata-with-asp-net-core) pattern. The message can be stored in TempData