# Capture URL Before Form Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to capture the URL submitted when the page loads. When the page loads, it's appended with provided parameters to give me information i need save off. The issue is when I have the user fill in form fields and submit, the URL contains the handler method. What seems obvious is that I need to capture the URL before the form is submitted. I'm not familiar enough w/ Razor to understand if there's an event that fires on load, or how to accomplish this. Is there something simple like a page load event? Thanks!

1) Starts as: https://localhost:44384/sign
2) On submit takes the handler name: https://localhost:44384/Sign?handler=SubmitAndRedirect

```
      <form method="post">
          First name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="on" maxlength="10" required><br>
          Last name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" autocomplete="on" maxlength="10" required><br>
          Employee number:<br>
          <input type="text" name="empnum" maxlength="10">
          <br>
          <br>I agree to the terms above:<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check" required>
          <button type="submit"  asp-page-handler="SubmitAndRedirect">Submit and Redirect</button>
      </form>
```

```
public ActionResult OnPostSubmitAndRedirect()
{

    //Capture Form Data and Push to SQL DB
    var firstname = Request.Form["firstname"];
    var lastname = Request.Form["lastname"];
    var empnum = Request.Form["empnum"];

    bool isValidUser = ValidateUser(empnum, lastname);

    if (isValidUser == true)
    {
        WriteToDB(firstname, lastname, empnum, url);
        return Redirect(hardcoded);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect("/sign");
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you need to use the value of the `handler` query parameter?

Comment: @Justin Turner - I think what you're really trying to ask is (how to detect whether a request is a postback)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820332/how-to-detect-postback-in-razor-page]

Comment: @gunr2171 I don't need to use the value of the handler parameter at all. I need the parameter values of the URL before the user clicks the submit btn to gather relevant information. The page is a splash screen with basic form to gather info about the users connecting to public wifi. The page is prefixed with something like http:server/node_id=0000000&node_mac=00:00:0a:00:00:00&gateway_id=292928&client_ip=100.00.00 and i want to grab those parameters. Once the form is submitted, the url obviously changes.

Comment: Thanks all. I was able to resolve adding a property on the C# side and then capture the request before the form was submitted by setting the property outside the form in paragraph tags. `<p>
    @{
        var QS = Request.QueryString.Value;
        JT.query = QS;
     }
    @*<h1> @JT.query</h1>*@
</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Model binding features of MVC might be what you're looking for. Take a look at [this article](https://mono.software/2017/02/09/model-binding-asp-net-mvc/).

See how it uses the `EmployeeViewModel` class and how the form gets posted to the action.

There is no `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` in MVC as in Web Forms that I'm aware of.

Also check out [jQuery's submit handler](https://api.jquery.com/submit/). Maybe this can allow you to capture some information and process it before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I was able to resolve adding a property on the C# side and then capture the request before the form was submitted by setting the property outside the form using inline code between paragraph tags.

```
<p>
    @{
        var QS = Request.QueryString.Value;
        JT.query = QS;
     }
    @*<h1> @JT.query</h1>*@
</p>
```